# How to set specific gpu in tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow

I want to specify the gpu to run my process. And I set it as follows:

```
import tensorflow as tf
with tf.device('/gpu:0'):
    a = tf.constant(3.0)
with tf.Session() as sess:
    while True:
        print sess.run(a)
```

However it still allocate memory in both my two gpus.

```
|    0      7479    C   python                         5437MiB 
|    1      7479    C   python                         5437MiB
```

Comment: TensorFlow initializes all GPUs it sees, you need to set `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES` to limit visible GPUs

Comment: Ok, I got it. thanks.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I believe that you need to set `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=1`. Or which ever GPU you want to use. If you make only one GPU visible, you will refer to it as `/gpu:0` in tensorflow regardless of what you set the environment variable to.

More info on that environment variable: https://devblogs.nvidia.com/cuda-pro-tip-control-gpu-visibility-cuda_visible_devices/

Comment: @ScottYang, try https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/using_gpu#using_a_single_gpu_on_a_multi-gpu_system

Comment: Using os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"]="0" like in the other answer allows the option to take user input on which GPU to use.

Answer (score 72):

There are 3 ways to achieve this:

1. Using `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES` environment variable.
   by setting environment variable `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES="1"` makes only device 1 visible and by setting `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES="0,1"` makes devices 0 and 1 visible. You can do this in python by having a line `os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"]="0,1"` after importing `os` package.
2. Using `with tf.device('/gpu:2')` and creating the graph. Then it will use GPU device 2 to run.
3. Using `config = tf.ConfigProto(device_count = {'GPU': 1})` and then `sess = tf.Session(config=config)`. This will use GPU device 1.

Comment: I have tried all the three methods. The second one still doesn't work. My demo code is shown as above.

Comment: In theory this should work, but sometimes you have to physically switch the graphics cards. Why? No idea! But it works for me when this method fails.

Comment: I don't think part three is entirely correct. As the name suggests `device_count` only sets the number of devices being used, not which. From the tf source code: 
```message ConfigProto {
  // Map from device type name (e.g., "CPU" or "GPU" ) to maximum
  // number of devices of that type to use.  If a particular device
  // type is not found in the map, the system picks an appropriate
  // number.
  map<string, int32> device_count = 1;```, see https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.11/tensorflow/core/protobuf/config.proto

Comment: Note that if `tf.ConfigProto(device_count = {'GPU': 0})` is set all will be runned on CPU, so it's not gpu_id, but number of gpus. Use `gpu_options = tf.GPUOptions(allow_growth=True, visible_device_list=str(gpu_id))`

Comment: Note that tf.Session is outdated as of 2020

Answer (score 54):

TF would allocate all available memory on each visible GPU if not told otherwise. Here are 5 ways to stick to just one (or a few) GPUs.

**Bash solution.** Set `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=0,1` in your terminal/console before starting python or jupyter notebook:

```
CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=0,1 python script.py
```

**Python solution.** run next 2 lines of code before constructing a session

```
import os
os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"]="0,1"
```

**Automated solution.** Method below will automatically detect GPU devices that are not used by other scripts and set CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES for you. You have to call `mask_unused_gpus` before constructing a session. It will filter out GPUs by current memory usage. This way you can run multiple instances of your script at once without changing your code or setting console parameters.

The function:

```
import subprocess as sp
import os

def mask_unused_gpus(leave_unmasked=1):
  ACCEPTABLE_AVAILABLE_MEMORY = 1024
  COMMAND = "nvidia-smi --query-gpu=memory.free --format=csv"

  try:
    _output_to_list = lambda x: x.decode('ascii').split('\n')[:-1]
    memory_free_info = _output_to_list(sp.check_output(COMMAND.split()))[1:]
    memory_free_values = [int(x.split()[0]) for i, x in enumerate(memory_free_info)]
    available_gpus = [i for i, x in enumerate(memory_free_values) if x > ACCEPTABLE_AVAILABLE_MEMORY]

    if len(available_gpus) < leave_unmasked: raise ValueError('Found only %d usable GPUs in the system' % len(available_gpus))
    os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"] = ','.join(map(str, available_gpus[:leave_unmasked]))
  except Exception as e:
    print('"nvidia-smi" is probably not installed. GPUs are not masked', e)

mask_unused_gpus(2)
```

Limitations: if you start multiple scripts at once it might cause a collision, because memory is not allocated immediately when you construct a session. In case it is a problem for you, you can use a randomized version as in original [source code: mask_busy_gpus()](https://github.com/yselivonchyk/TensorFlow_DCIGN/blob/master/utils.py)

**Tensorflow 2.0** suggest yet another method:

```
gpus = tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')
if gpus:
  # Restrict TensorFlow to only use the first GPU
  try:
    tf.config.experimental.set_visible_devices(gpus[0], 'GPU')
  except RuntimeError as e:
    # Visible devices must be set at program startup
    print(e)
```

**Tensorflow/Keras** also allows to specify gpu to be used with session config. I can recommend it only if setting environment variable is not an options (i.e. an MPI run). Because it tend to be the least reliable of all methods, especially with keras.

```
config = tf.ConfigProto()
config.gpu_options.visible_device_list = "0,1"
with tf.Session(config) as sess:
#or K.set_session(tf.Session(config))
```

Comment: The selected answer is technically correct but this is the best way to handle this scenario.

Comment: For **Bash solution**, shouldn't it be `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=0,1 python script.py`, without `$` ahead of the env variable `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES`?

Answer (score 7):

You can modify the GPU options settings by adding at the begining of your **python** script:

```py
gpu_options = tf.GPUOptions(visible_device_list="0")
sess = tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(gpu_options=gpu_options))
```

"0" is here the name of the GPU you want to use. You can have the list of the GPU available by typing the command nvidia-smi in the terminal prompt.

---

With Keras, these 2 functions allow the selection of CPU or GPU and in the case of GPU the fraction of memory that will be used.

```py
import os
from keras.backend.tensorflow_backend import set_session
import tensorflow as tf



def set_cpu_option():
    os.environ["CUDA_DEVICE_ORDER"] = "PCI_BUS_ID"  # see issue #152
    os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"] = ""
    os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"] = ""


def set_gpu_option(which_gpu, fraction_memory):
    config = tf.ConfigProto()
    config.gpu_options.per_process_gpu_memory_fraction = fraction_memory
    config.gpu_options.visible_device_list = which_gpu
    set_session(tf.Session(config=config))
    return

set_gpu_option("0", 0.9)
# or 
set_cpu_option()
```

Comment: It gives me `undefined name set_session, undefined name logger`

Answer (score 2):

```
def set_specific_gpu(ID):
    gpus_all_physical_list = tf.config.list_physical_devices(device_type='GPU')    
    tf.config.set_visible_devices(gpus_all_physical_list[ID], 'GPU')
```

refer to https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/config/list_physical_devices

Answer (score 2):

```
import tensorflow as tf


gpu_number = 2 #### GPU number 
gpus = tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')
if gpus:
    tf.config.experimental.set_visible_devices(gpus[gpu_number], 'GPU') 
    logical_gpus = tf.config.experimental.list_logical_devices('GPU')
    print(len(gpus), "Physical GPUs,", len(logical_gpus), "Logical GPU")
```

Answer (score 1):

The most elegant and clean way I have seen this work for me on my multi-core gpu setup is:

```
import os
os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"]="1"
tf_device='/gpu:0'
```

This assigns the task to gpu device 1.

Similarly, doing something on the lines:

```
import os 
os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"]="2"
tf_device='/gpu:0'
```

The os.environ command can be seen as a way of making only that GPU device exposed on which you intend to run the code. The second command just picks the first of the available devices that you specified.

[image]

Comment: No, it's not elegant to set environment variables of the same process. You should set them before you run the process, for example: `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=XYZ python script.py`

Answer (score 1):

```
import os
os.environ["CUDA_DEVICE_ORDER"]="PCI_BUS_ID"   # see issue #152
os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"]="3"
```

The only thing which worked for me cleanly from within Processes to assign specific GPU to each process in a Pool.

Answer (score 1):

`TF 2.9` and above version of `tensorflow` has changed the APIs, so updating for the same,

```
gpus = tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')
gpu_id = 0
if gpus:
    # Restrict TensorFlow to only use only one GPU based on gpu_id
    try:
        tf.config.set_visible_devices(gpus[gpu_id], 'GPU')
        logical_gpus = tf.config.list_logical_devices('GPU')
        print(len(gpus), "Physical GPUs,", len(logical_gpus), "Logical GPU")
    except RuntimeError as e:
        # Visible devices must be set before GPUs have been initialized
        print(e)
```