# tensorflow: training network on one GPU but occupy the space of the other

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning

I have two GPUs, and I just would like to use one GPU to train a network by tensorflow. When I train it, the code use all the memories of two GPUs, but only one GPU is working:

[image]

I do not know why and how to solve this problem.

Comment: do `export CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=0` before running your script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default tensorflow will occupy consume the memory of all available GPUs. You can either set allow growth as per @sygi's answer or make only one of the GPUs visible to tensorflow as per Yaroslav's comment. And as per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40069883/how-to-set-specific-gpu-in-tensorflow/41024999).

Comment: Finally, I use both ways.

Answer (score 2):

Try setting:

```
config = tf.ConfigProto()
config.gpu_options.allow_growth=True
sess = tf.Session(config=config)
```

as in [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34199233/how-to-prevent-tensorflow-from-allocating-the-totality-of-a-gpu-memory).