# Keras multi-gpu: specifying explicit GPU ids

Tags: tensorflow, keras, multi-gpu

From looking at the file `keras/utils/multi_gpu_utils.py` in tensorflow GitHub repository, I could see that given that you specified that you want to use `x` GPUs, it will automatically allocate the GPU IDs from `range(x)`, i.e., `0, 1, 2, ..., x - 1`.

I need to use GPUs `4, 5, 6 ,7`, since the first 4 GPUs are already working on another task. Is there a way to specify it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In python you can use

```
import os
os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"]="0,1"
```

Or set `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=0,1` in bash before starting python script

You can also refer to my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40069883/how-to-set-specific-gpu-in-tensorflow) to automate this process.

Comment: Thanks. sounds simple and amazing. I'll update you once I try

Comment: It really worked. Thank you for the simple and very helpful answer. Note that I used `export CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=4,5,6,7`, according to my GPU availability