# Tensorflow 2 string labels to one_hot

Tags: python, tensorflow2.0

I am trying to fit a model with string labels in form `["aa", "aa", "bb", "bb", "bb", "cc"]` and wanted to use `tf.one_hot(labels, depth=3)` to get the one hot vectors but I get the error:

```
NotFoundError: Could not find valid device for node.
Node:{{node OneHot}}
All kernels registered for op OneHot :
  device='XLA_GPU'; TI in [DT_INT32, DT_UINT8, DT_INT64]; T in [DT_FLOAT, DT_DOUBLE, DT_INT32, DT_UINT8, DT_INT16, ..., DT_UINT16, DT_COMPLEX128, DT_HALF, DT_UINT32, DT_UINT64]
  device='XLA_CPU'; TI in [DT_INT32, DT_UINT8, DT_INT64]; T in [DT_FLOAT, DT_DOUBLE, DT_INT32, DT_UINT8, DT_INT16, ..., DT_UINT16, DT_COMPLEX128, DT_HALF, DT_UINT32, DT_UINT64]
```

my questions:

1- is it even possible to transform these kind of label to one hot directly with `tensorflow 2` or should the input be `INT`?

2- if yes what could cause this problem

3-is it possible to fit a model directly with string labels?

extra information:

I am using a cluster to train and using `GPU` and defined my device using `os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"]="2"` based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40069883/how-to-set-specific-gpu-in-tensorflow)

I will post more of my code if it's necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1- is it even possible to transform these kind of label to one hot directly with tensorflow 2 or should the input be INT?

2- if yes what could cause this problem

> TensorFlow only supports numeric indices. If you look at the documentation for [`tf.one_hot`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/one_hot), it is in fact an index you are passing as the labels. I found this info via this [Github issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs/issues/1108#issuecomment-456954171)

3-is it possible to fit a model directly with string labels?

> I don't see an easy way out for this. But if you can fit your data in-memory, I'd suggest using pandas/sklearn and convert these to onehot encoded. If it doesn't you might need to create a series of feature columns for your data. For example [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/feature_column/categorical_column_with_vocabulary_list) feature column supports what you need to achieve.

Comment: Thanks for the reply I got that through further reading in documentations. I  will leave this for future matters: 1-one hot vector is being used for categorical crossentropy and integer labels is being used for sparse categorical crossentropy. I changes my labels to integers and matched with my loss function and it worked.