# Tensorflow not detecting GPU where as Pytorch does

Tags: python, tensorflow, pytorch, gpu

ubuntu 18.04,
nvidia mx150,
cuda 10.1,
tensorflow installed using both `$ pip install tensorflow` and `$ pip install tensorflow-gpu`.
the problem is that it doesn't detect the GPU, but when tried with pytorch it does. cant seem to find the problem.
Thanks in advance.
[Jupyterlab output when tried to test GPU](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kllUu.png)

edit 1 - I have set the CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES to 0, i'm able to detect the GPU manually but tensorflow is not able to, i did not try the source build option yet.[image: manual detection]

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways for you to check if TensorFlow is detecting a GPU or not. Please try the following and update the question based on which Ill update my answer further.

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
  devices = sess.list_devices()
```

Also,

```
from tensorflow.python.client import device_lib
print(device_lib.list_local_devices())
```

In case you are able to detect the GPU but TensorFlow is not set to it, there may be an issue with your environment variables. There are quite a lot of threads that talk about how to set a GPU for TensorFlow on SO.

From [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40069883/how-to-set-specific-gpu-in-tensorflow) -

1. Using CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES environment variable. by setting environment variable CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES="1" makes only device 1 visible and by setting CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES="0,1" makes devices 0 and 1 visible. You can do this in python by having a line os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"]="0,1" after importing os package.
2. Using with tf.device('/gpu:2') and creating the graph. Then it will use GPU device 2 to run.
3. Using config = tf.ConfigProto(device_count = {'GPU': 1}) and then sess = tf.Session(config=config). This will use GPU device 1.

Finally, if none of the above solves it, then check [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/38990) on the official TensorFlow repo. Someone answered here by saying that their issues were resolved after building TensorFlow from source. [Here is a link](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source#common_installation_problems) for how to do that.