# CUDA 11.8 not recognized by Tensorflow but Pytorch does

Tags: python, tensorflow, ubuntu

I am currently working on a machine learning project using Ubuntu 23 with an RTX 3060 Ti GPU. I have successfully installed CUDA 11.8, and **PyTorch is functioning perfectly**, recognizing and utilizing the GPU without any issues.

However, I am encountering difficulties with TensorFlow. Despite installing the `tensorflow[and-cuda]` package, TensorFlow does not seem to recognize the GPU. I have checked and confirmed that the CUDA toolkit and cuDNN are correctly installed:

```
2023-11-19 10:04:21.667041: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:182] This TensorFlow binary is optimized to use available CPU instructions in performance-critical operations.
To enable the following instructions: AVX2 FMA, in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
2023-11-19 10:04:22.398453: W tensorflow/compiler/tf2tensorrt/utils/py_utils.cc:38] TF-TRT Warning: Could not find TensorRT
2023-11-19 10:04:23.228798: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:995] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero. See more at https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v6.0/Documentation/ABI/testing/sysfs-bus-pci#L344-L355
2023-11-19 10:04:23.257218: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1960] Cannot dlopen some GPU libraries. Please make sure the missing libraries mentioned above are installed properly if you would like to use GPU. Follow the guide at https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu for how to download and setup the required libraries for your platform.
Skipping registering GPU devices...
```

When I try:

```
from tensorflow.python.client import device_lib

print(device_lib.list_local_devices())
```

returns only:

```
[name: "/device:CPU:0"
device_type: "CPU"
memory_limit: 268435456
locality {
}
incarnation: 5180605997013099642
xla_global_id: -1
]
```

Here are the relevant details:

- Operating System: Ubuntu 23
- GPU: RTX 3060 Ti
- CUDA version: 11.8

PyTorch is running smoothly with GPU support, but TensorFlow refuses to acknowledge the GPU presence.

I have followed the usual installation steps, including the installation of the CUDA toolkit, cuDNN, and the TensorFlow package with GPU support. However, when I run TensorFlow code, it defaults to CPU execution.

Any insights or guidance on resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated. If there are specific steps or configurations for TensorFlow on Ubuntu 23 with an RTX 3060 Ti that I might be missing, please let me know.

Thank you in advance for your assistance!

Comment: Does this solution help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65085515/tensorflow-not-detecting-gpu-where-as-pytorch-does

Comment: Also, we do not know the details of your tensorflow installation. How about removing tensorflow and a clean install again?