# GPU not recognized after building tensorflow==1.15.4 from source with CUDA 10.2

Tags: tensorflow, build, gpu

For some code that I want to replicate, I need to install `tensorflow==1.15.4` with GPU support. Unfortunately, the pre-built binary is [compiled with CUDA 10.0](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source#gpu), but I have CUDA 10.2 on my system.

Thus, I wanted to install it from source and build it myself. I've followed [these official instructions](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source). During `configure` I selected always the default value except for `Do you wish to build TensorFlow with CUDA support? [y/N]:` which I answered with `Y`. I used the following build command:

```sh
bazel build --config=v1 --config=cuda //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package
```

I think the `--config=cuda` is redundant here, but I included it anyway to make sure.

I initially encountered an error during build, which I could resolve with [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/34429#issuecomment-557408498). After that, the compilation completed successfully.

To my surprise, running the following snippet after the installation indicates, that my GPU is still not available to use with `tensorflow`.

```py
import tensorflow as tf


tf.test.is_built_with_cuda()  # True
tf.test.is_gpu_available()  # False
```

Can someone can tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Are you certain that the tensorflow you import and call is actually the one you built?

Comment: @talonmies It seems so. Running `python -c "import tensorflow as tf; print('\n'.join(tf.__path__))"` resulted in [this output](https://gist.github.com/pmeier/eeff323b0b3fd4069d8cbc423964a74c). This is the library I installed the built wheel in.

Comment: Found the issue: I had `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=1` as environment variable as indicated in [the sample code I'm trying to replicate](https://github.com/CompVis/adaptive-style-transfer#training). If I set this to `0` or unset it completely the GPU is recognized. Do you know the reason behind it? If so, could you create an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: You can and should create you own answer. It is perfectly OK to answer your own question

Comment: @talonmies I'm aware of that. But in that case the answer wouldn't include a reason on why the fix works. If you don't know either, I'm happy to answer it myself.

Comment: You are asking me to answer something which you did involving details which are not even in your question. I couldn't do that even if I wanted to, which I don't

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set specific gpu in tensorflow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40069883/how-to-set-specific-gpu-in-tensorflow)

Comment: @talonmies Kinda. With `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=1` I've hid my GPU with index 0 from `tensorflow` without knowing it. Of course I'm to blame here, since I used code without understanding it, but including a line like this in a "tutorial" seems dangerous at best. Thanks for your insights.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [code I was trying to replicate](https://github.com/CompVis/adaptive-style-transfer#training) had `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=1` set as environment variable. Out of inexperience with Tensorflow I also set this without understanding what I meant.

Since I have only a single GPU, i.e. index 0, my GPU was not recognized. Thus, this had nothing to do with the build, which worked as intended.