# How to know which GPU device is currently being used in Python?

Tags: python, nvidia

I have two `NVIDIA` devices in my docker. Here is the GPU usage information when two models are running at the same time.

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
Mon May 31 10:51:54 2021       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 418.43       Driver Version: 418.43       CUDA Version: 10.1     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GTX 108...  Off  | 00000000:03:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| 37%   64C    P2    81W / 250W |  10909MiB / 11178MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   1  GeForce GTX 108...  Off  | 00000000:04:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| 28%   50C    P8     9W / 250W |    147MiB / 11178MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                               
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

It is obviously two models are using device `0`. Here I have two questions:

1. How can I know which device is used?
2. If one model uses device `0`, can we automatically let another model uses device `1`?

Answer (score 0):

I would say Python itself is not using a GPU per se, but rather a framework like Torch... are you using a machine learning framework here?

Comment: I am using tensorflow.

Comment: Could be related to this question then:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38009682/how-to-tell-if-tensorflow-is-using-gpu-acceleration-from-inside-python-shell

If any GPU device is available to TensorFlow, it should pop up there

Comment: As for how to specify the device to be used, this here could help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40069883/how-to-set-specific-gpu-in-tensorflow